# how does ffmpeg generate configure script file?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is no AutoTools script file such as makefile.am or configure.ac.
how can I regenerate a ‘configure’ script file? and what is the .mak file?
I see even the option of configure script is also different from traditional configure script ,there is no --build, --target option. Is it using a different building system?

Comment: You run './configure' with options for the ffmpeg build which then generates the make files.

Answer (score 2):

configure file and most of makefiles are written by hand and not generated. Every generated file can be updated by rerunning configure/make.

Comment: who writes the configure file then ? do you mean the ffmpeg developers put it together?

Comment: It is exactly what I meant. Ffmpeg developers maintain it.

Comment: I was getting libsnappy not found even when the `CFLAGS` is set to snappy's include path in the `configure`.